# C++ Limpiar solo una parte de la pantalla

Tags: c++

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int edad;
string nombre;
cout<<"Hola mundo"<<endl;
cout<<"Como estan?"<<endl;
cout<<"Ingresa tu edad"<<endl;
cin>>edad;
cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre"<<endl;
cin>>nombre;
//Digamos que la persona ingreso numeros en el nombre
//Quiero borrar la ultima parte y no todo
return 0;
}
```

Lo que deseo hacer es borrar una lineas de la consola, lo de arriba es solo un ejemplo.

En pocas palabras no quiero hacer `system ("cls")` solo borrar una parte de la pantalla.

Como le hago?

Comment: Me parece que el `return` quedó afuera de las llaves, ¿está bien?

Comment: De hecho si el return 0; queda fuera de main no podría compilar el programa.

Comment: Ya lo arregle, es que escribi el ejemplo directamente aca en la pagina

Comment: @Malthael ¿podrías decir el compilador y el sistema operativo que estás usando?

Comment: @Malthael He agregado una respuesta, pero cual es el objetivo de esto?

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET estoy usando windows 10 y dev ++

Comment: @Elenasys estoy haciendo un programa donde se ingresan varios datos el problema es que no deseo borrar todo sino hasta cierto punto, por ejemplo, ingreso nombres, numero, edad etc, y digamos que el usario se equivoco en lo ultimo pero lo demas esta bien, no deseo borrar todo sino hasta cierto punto

Comment: Yo tengo una alternativa, pero hay que usar `cls` y técnicas avanzadas como la concatenación de cadenas _strings_. Se trata de guardar en memoria, es decir, en una cadena, el texto que aparece en pantalla, y eliminar lo que no se quiera mostrar pero desde ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo solucione este problema usando una combinacion de la *funcion gotoxy y system("clear")* aqui le dejo el codigo de la funcion gotoxy x si alguien más la necesita:

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y){
      HANDLE hcon;
      hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
      COORD dwPos;
      dwPos.X = x;
      dwPos.Y= y;
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  }
```

No se olviden de agregar las *librerias windows.h y stdlib.h*, ya con eso pueden crear funciones con bucles para limpiar partes de la pantalla

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `cout<<"\e[A";` pero en tu caso al imprimir la última línea usas `endl`,
tendrías que usar dos veces esta instrucción:

```
int main ()
{
cout<<"Hola mundo"<<endl;
cout<<"Como estan?"<<endl;
cout<<"Esta linea dice x cosa"<<endl;
//quiero borrar solo la linea de arriba y no todo
cout<<"\e[A";
cout<<"\e[A";
return 0;
}
```

Tendrías como salida únicamente :

```
Hola mundo
Como estan?
```

Lo que realiza al mandar como salida `"\e[A"` es un [history-search backward](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/the-most-important-command-line-tip-incremental-history-searching-with-inputrc/).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mm lo probare y vere que tal

Comment: ¿Funcionarán en Windows esas secuencias de escape?

Comment: no funciono, gracias de todas formas Elenasys

Comment: @Malthael lo acabo de probar y me funciono :|, agregue una imagen. Tal vez exista una diferencia al usar Dev ++ .

Comment: @Elenasys estas usando codeblocks? o cual IDE?

Comment: Lo probé con Netbeans, estoy usando Cygwin gcc-c++ como compilador, tal vez esta es la diferencia, más tarde pruebo en Dev-C++.